# Pass argument to constructor using ethers.js during deploy

Tags: solidity, ethers.js

How to pass constructor arguments (`name`) to the contract in `deploy` using `ethers.js`.
Here is my code:

```
    const deployContract = async (abi: InterfaceAbi, bytecode: string) => {
        console.log(signer.current);
        if (!signer.current) {
            throw new Error("Signer not connected");
        }

        const factory = new ethers.ContractFactory(abi, bytecode, signer.current);
        await factory.deploy(parseEther("0"));
    };
```

and this is the contract:

```
contract CompanyContract {
    string public name;
    mapping(address => Review) public reviews;
    uint public rate;

    event ReviewAdded(string company, Review review);

    struct Review {
        uint rate;
        string comment;
        address author;
    }

    constructor(string memory _name) {
        console.log("CompanyContract created by:", msg.sender);
        name = _name;
    }

    function addReview(Review memory _review) public {
        reviews[msg.sender] = _review;
        emit ReviewAdded(name, _review);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh I was already passing a parameter to the constructor:

```
await factory.deploy(parseEther("0"));
```

So I changed the param for a name:

```
await factory.deploy("Company Name");
```